# Can Green Lanterns make copies of their Power ring?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Suppose that a Green Lantern agent wants to assign a friend of his as his/her deputy for certain reason: for example, ensuring the safety of his home world while he/she is fighting crime several light years away. Could he/she use his/her willpower to create a copy of his/her ring?

Granted, the process might require a huge amount of power (from the ring and from its user), perhaps too much for it to be practical (conservation of energy), but could you make, at the very least, an imperfect copy in theory?

Just to get extraneous issues out of the way, let's assume this friend of agent is strong-willed enough to be a ring-bearer (perhaps even a prospective Lantern!), and the Guardians have sanctioned this experiment for the time being (out of sympathy or at least scientific curiosity).

Furthermore, I believe Jordan's Green power ring has been 'copied' in at least one comic story-line (Superman: Red Son), though I haven't really read it and don't quite know how that universe's Jordan accomplished it.

Comment: Since none of the answers have mentioned your *Red Son* comment yet: as I recall, in that story Jordan didn't copy anything, he was just one of the people who was given a human-made ring designed by Lex Luthor, based on reverse-engineered tech from the actual Green Lantern ring found on Abin Sur.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_ring_(DC_Comics)#Capabilities) :

> A power ring is also capable of creating fully functional duplicates
>   of itself

This happened in  **Green Lantern: Rebirth #3 (February 2005)** where Hal Jordan's ring duplicates itself multiple times

Also as mentioned [here](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Power_Ring), Among the many powers of a power ring :

> **Ring Duplication**: Most Power Rings are capable of automatically duplicating themselves. Each duplicate typically shares the qualities
>   and capabilities of the original ring. Each duplicate still requires
>   to be recharged by a personal power battery. Some "temporary" rings
>   can also be made, as well as rings with severe limitations and
>   pre-programmed commands. All power rings, as being based upon the
>   green ring templates created by the Guardians of the Universe, are all
>   programmed to be able to duplicate themselves on a specialised command
>   known apparently only by the Guardians.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of Green Lantern #4 (New 52) Sinestro, as a Green Lantern, creates at least a dozen copies of his ring. The strain from creating so many copies nearly breaks his ring, which he claims to have done twice before. He does this to arm his people on Korugar against the Yellow Lanterns besieging the planet.

The whole first arc of New 52 Green Lantern is great, but it's worth reading for this scene alone.

**Additional Info:**

In that story, the copies created have all the same abilities as the base ring, but carry a much smaller charge. Also, increasing the number of copies made at one time decreases the charge held by each individual ring, so the case OP describes of only one copy being made would be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

Kyle Rayner has given a copy of Hal Jordan's power ring to Jade once. So it is possible to make copy of Green Lantern's ring.

Not sure exactly which issue it was, maybe, Green Lantern: The New Corps #1. In this story-line, Kyle Rayner attempts to rebuild the Green Lantern Corps.

Comment: Can you confirm in which comics serial this occurred?

Comment: The answer is correct. I will hunt down a reference once I am home from work.