# Can a Green Lantern's construct exist independently of the Green Lantern? And for how long?

Tags: green-lantern, dc-animated-universe, dc

If a Green Lantern can [create a power ring for someone else](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80454/20393).

Can the Green Lantern then leave the new ring with that person indefinitely?

How long will the ring last?

Are there any example of this in any canon?

Comment: @cde I actually reference that question in my question... If you look closely, it's a different question entirely.

Comment: Ajo answer on that question answers your question completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, a Green Lantern can duplicate their ring and give it to a prospective Green Lantern.

- The duplicate is a real ring but the new recruit will have to share a Power Battery until they can get their own from Oa.
- The new ring is not an energy construct. It takes material from the original ring and available matter to create a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Green lantern rings (and the other rainbow corps) can Create both *actual* ring duplicates, with or without limitations built in, **AND** hard light constructs copies that will run out like any other lantern construct.